# Is it possible to explicitly lock the screen without Ventura going to sleep?

Tags: sleep-wake, bug, screen-lock, ventura

I'm transferring files. I want to lock the screen but prevent the transfer from pausing upon doing so, as it currently does. This appears to be buggy. If I wanted the machine to sleep, I would select sleep from the menu, not lock. Why do they both do the same thing?

This isn't the first time I've encountered this. I end up not locking the machine, turning off the 'turn off' display settings, and just turn the brightness down. I've tried apps as well, with some success.

I want to be able to select Lock Screen but not have the machine sleep, without any apps. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe just turn on the ScreenSaver, and require a password to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use the `caffeinate` terminal command (built-in), or the [Wimoweh app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wimoweh/id610341008?mt=12) from the App Store ($1.99)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76107/how-can-i-keep-my-mac-awake-and-locked

Answer (score 1):

**System Settings** > **Display** > **Advanced…**: Prevent automatic sleeping when the display is off [x]